# How to run DDL script with kinterbasdb

Tags: python, firebird, ddl, kinterbasdb

Is there way to execute DDL script from Python with kinterbasdb library for Firebird database?

Basically I'd like to replicate 'isql -i myscript.sql' command.

Answer (score 2):

It has been a while since I used kinterbasdb, but as far as I know you should be able to do this with any query command which can also be used for INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE (ie nothing that produces a resultset). So Connection.execute_immediate and Cursor.execute should work.

Did you actually try this.

BTW: With Firebird it is advisable not to mix DDL and DML in one transaction.

**EDIT:**
I just realised that you might have meant a full DDL script with multiple statements, if that is what you mean, then: no you cannot, you need to execute each statement individually.

You might be able to use an EXECUTE BLOCK statement, but you may need to modify your script so much that it would be easier to simply try to split the actual script into individual statements.